# Ubuntu One wont connect with an authentication failure

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one

I have set up account.  Can sign in from browser,  Have registered Android phone.  Can NOT connect from Natty.  Message when I try to sign in: An exception representing an authentication failure.  I have reset password to no avail.  thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you're forgetting that Ubuntu One password is case-sensitive and you're typing it in lower case.

Comment: Case sensitivity is not the issue.  Re set password four times.  I can sign in via Internet and Android phone

Answer (score 1):

There's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-control-panel/+bug/703507) filled for this issue, according to some [comments](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-control-panel/+bug/703507/comments/9) in the report the solution is to change the timezone.

Comment: Where would I see the timezone discrepancy?

Comment: Click on the clock on the upper right corner, go to *time & date settings*. A window will open (with a lock on the upper left corner), in there you can check out the timezone settings

Comment: BINGO!!  That did it.  Reset time to appropriate zone.  Thanks Fido!